# Querying SQL table with LINQ and XElement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I don't know if this is possible to do but, I want to retrieve from a table in SQL a few fields plus a specific value inside an XML field in the table e.g.

```
MyTable(UserName varchar(50),XML_Response XML)
```

note: the data type in C# for value in field `XML_Response` is `XElement`

The XML inside field `XML_Response` bellow can be in two forms *with* | *without* value inside tag Update Result description:

```
<IntegrationResults>
  <UpdateResult>Failure</UpdateResult>
  <UpdateResultDescription>LeadId 2876474 not found</UpdateResultDescription>
</IntegrationResults>
<IntegrationResults>
    <UpdateResult>Success</UpdateResult>
    <UpdateResultDescription />
</IntegrationResults>
```

My query output I want to look like this (2 rows as examples)

```
"My User Name","LeadId 83608 not found"
"My User Name 2",""
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to what you are trying, you can use a C# command object and run the below SQL directly on the table:

```
SELECT UserName
      , IntegrationResults.n.value('UpdateResultDescription[1]','VARCHAR(200)') as UpdateResultDescription
  FROM  MyTable
        outer apply MyTable.XML_Response.nodes('/IntegrationResults') AS IntegrationResults(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you everyone, I was able to find a solution:

```
.select(x => new
{
   x.UserName,
   UpdateResult = x.MyTable.XML_Response.Element("UpdateResult").Value,
   UpdateResultDescription = x.MyTable.XML_Response.Element("UpdateResultDescription").Value,
});
```